# How to integrate Zbrush with Blender for long run animation projects?

Tags: workflow, export

I have years of experience with Zbrush though I am learning blender right now.

I would like to model characters in Zbrush bring them into Blender for animation.

Please let me know what is the best work flow for it. If you can share any tutorial or link for it, even that will help.

I have not found any book which can let me know about this process.

There are many for zbrush and max/ maya but not blender.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/06/03/using-gob-zbrush-applink-blender/) is a [plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/GoB_ZBrush_import_export) for blender that allows for a very good degree of integration between z-brush and blender.

Comment: I am not sure Goz detects Blender. It never detected it before. I will try rechecking it.

Comment: I have checked Goz not detecting Blender.

Answer (score 3):

By default Zbrush wont detect Blender.
You will need to install the plugin manually that GiantCowFilms suggested.

However the link posted only includes the blender side. For the zbrush side you will need to download another link. It comes with instructions on how to install.

This video from CGcookie has instructions and links on how to get it working.
[Using the GoB Zbrush Applink with Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2ZSxxWmrQc)

Answer (score 3):

**Q. How do I move a sculpt from ZBrush to Blender?**

A. These workflow methods assume that you have everything set up properly for the [GoB 2.72 add-on](http://www.zbrushcentral.com/attachment.php?s=1564d4ba10a4148b0d339bda5033f551&attachmentid=435807&d=1418198854) on both the Blender and ZBrush side, it is working as it should and you have confirmed this with prior testing.

*Method 1 – Pre-open Blender before sending from ZBrush to Blender using GoZ*

- Open Blender and enable the GoB 2.72 add-on
- Optional: Clear the Blender scene for simplicity sake.
- Open ZBrush and select the SubTool that you want to transfer to
  Blender.
- In ZBrush, go into Geometry choose the subdivision level that you want and then
  delete the lower subdivision levels.
- In ZBrush, make sure that Blender is the current GoZ application and then press
  GoZ.
- In Blender, press the green GoB import button.
- Note: You can have this toggle button enabled beforehand and the
  subtool will auto import when GoZ in pressed in ZBrush.

*Method 2 – Open Blender after sending from ZBrush to Blender using GoZ*

- Open ZBrush and select your SubTool that you want to transfer.
- In ZBrush, go into Geometry choose the subdivision level that you want and then
  delete the lower subdivision levels.
- In ZBrush, make sure that Blender is the current GoZ application and then press
  GoZ.
- Open Blender and enable the GoB 2.72 add-on.
- In Blender, press the green GoB import button and the mesh will
  import.

(workflows tested and working with Blender 2.77a)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with deleting lower subdivision levels. Just tried GoB out and was wondering how to get my subdivisions in ZBrush over.