# Can I Move a mesh from Zbrush to Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, zbrush

There is a way to transfer a mesh from Zbrush to Blender?

I'm using Blender 2.77 and Zbrush 4R7.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13426/zbrush-model-blender-animation and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13381/how-to-integrate-zbrush-with-blender-for-long-run-animation-projects

Comment: And i also suggest you to use Decimation Master in ZBrush before exporting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

Export your model from ZBrush as .obj (Wavefront Object). Even the texture can be exported on this way.

Then in Blender, "File -> Import -> Wavefront OBJ..." Make sure you have "Image Search" checked on and it will look for and import the textures as a Blender Internal material.